# How can I smoothly load the data from the adapter and set into the fragment listview in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

Explanation:
           I have implement a navigationDrawer. In which myFirstFragment it means in my homeFragment,I have viewpager and listview.I have set my data and data loaded completely in both.

When I click on one of the row of the listview,it calls a class name GetValue and inside the GetValue.I passed an intent to open an activity namely ScoreCard.

In Scorecard,I have implemented a tablayout with viewpager so I have multiple fragments inside my ScoreCard.Fragment like ONE,TWO,THREE etc.

My All the fragment which load the data from the server.

Everything working correctly but the problem is when I click on the row of the listview which was set into my home_fragment it loaded scorecard and scorecard loaded the fragment.

During the load of the fragment,I press back button of my device and application was unfortunately crashed.

Here is post some code which work after pressing the row of the listview which reside on homeFragment.

Here is my homeFragment in which I call and adapter and set the value to the listview.

```
ScheduleAdapter CmAdapter = new ScheduleAdapter(getContext(), arr_completed, lst_key2);
CmAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
completed_listview.setAdapter(CmAdapter);
```

Here is ScheduleAdapter.java

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        match_key = arr_matchKey.get(position);
        Log.e("Schedule complted key", match_key);
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) context;
        GetValue gv = new GetValue(context);
        gv.setFullUrl(match_key);
        gv.setAccessToken(activity.getMyData());
        gv.execute();
    }
});
```

Here is my GetValue.java class which get the data from server and called ScoreCard activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if(st_overview.equals("abandoned") || st_overview.equals("canceled"))
        {
            DialogAbandoned ad=new DialogAbandoned(context);
            ad.setDialog(short_name,msg_info+".");
        }
        else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScoreCard.class);
            intent.putExtra("tabvalue", tabVlaue);
            intent.putExtra("teamName", name_of_team);
            intent.putExtra("tabData", tabData);
            intent.putExtra("match_key", match_key);
            intent.putExtra("access_token", accessToken);
            intent.putExtra("team_names", teams_name);
            intent.putExtra("inn_len", inn_len);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Here is my ScoreCard.java activity which have tablayout with viewpager

```
public class ScoreCard extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    public ViewPager viewPager;
    public TabLayout tabLayout;

    String[] team_name = new String[10];
    String[] runs = new String[4];
    String[] wicket = new String[4];

    String[] name_of_team_split;
    public String[] parts, parts1;

    public String name_of_team = "";
    public String tab_value = "";
    public String match_key = "";
    public String tabData = "";
    public int tabSelector;
    public String access_token = "";
    public String header_team_name = "";

    int inn_len = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_card);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

        Intent i = getIntent();
        tab_value = i.getStringExtra("tabvalue");
        tabData = i.getStringExtra("tabData");
        name_of_team = i.getStringExtra("teamName");
        inn_len = i.getIntExtra("inn_len", 0);
        match_key = i.getStringExtra("match_key");
        access_token = i.getStringExtra("access_token");
        header_team_name = i.getStringExtra("team_names");

        if (header_team_name != null && header_team_name != "") {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(header_team_name);
        }
        try {
            parts1 = tabData.split("`");
            int k = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < parts1.length; a++, k++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parts1[a]);
                    runs[k] = obj.getString("runs");
                    wicket[k] = obj.getString("wickets");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            name_of_team_split = name_of_team.split("=");

            for (int b = 0; b < name_of_team_split.length; b++) {
                JSONObject team1 = new JSONObject(name_of_team_split[b]);
                team_name[b] = team1.getString("short_name");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setTabValue(tab_value);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        if (tabSelector == 1) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, false);
        } else if (tabSelector == 2) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
        } else if (tabSelector == 3) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false);
        } else if (tabSelector == 4) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(4, false);
        }
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        if (tabSelector == 1) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(team_name[0] + "-" + runs[0] + "/" + wicket[0]);
        } else if (tabSelector == 2) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(team_name[0] + "-" + runs[0] + "/" + wicket[0]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(team_name[1] + "-" + runs[1] + "/" + wicket[1]);
        } else if (tabSelector == 3) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(team_name[0] + "-" + runs[0] + "/" + wicket[0]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(team_name[1] + "-" + runs[1] + "/" + wicket[1]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText(team_name[2] + "-" + runs[2] + "/" + wicket[2]);
        } else if (tabSelector == 4) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(team_name[0] + "\n" + runs[0] + "/" + wicket[0]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(team_name[1] + "\n" + runs[1] + "/" + wicket[1]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText(team_name[2] + "\n" + runs[2] + "/" + wicket[2]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setText(team_name[3] + "\n" + runs[3] + "/" + wicket[3]);
        }
    }

    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        if (tabSelector == 1) {
            adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment());
        } else if (tabSelector == 2) {
            adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment());
            adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment());
        } else if (tabSelector == 3) {
            adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment());
            adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment());
            adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment());
        } else if (tabSelector == 4) {
            adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment());
            adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment());
            adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment());
            adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment());
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void setTabValue(String tabs) {
        parts = tabs.split(",");

        int len = parts.length;

        if (len == 1) {
            tabSelector = 1;
        } else if (len == 2) {
            tabSelector = 2;
        } else if (len == 3) {
            tabSelector = 3;
        } else if (len == 4) {
            tabSelector = 4;
        }
    }

    public String setInningScore() {
        return tab_value;
    }

    public String geturl() {
        return match_key;
    }

    public String GetAccessToken() {
        return access_token;
    }

    public int setInningLength() {
        return inn_len;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        if(menu!=null){
            menu.findItem(R.id.Score).setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my OneFragent which calls from scorecard. I only post the code which required according to my question

```
adapter = new FullScoreAdapter(getContext(), p_name, p_key);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
lst.setAdapter(adapter);
Helper.getListViewSize(lst);
```

above adapter calls the FullScoreAdapter and set the data into listview of the OneFragment

Here is my FullScoreAdapter

```
public class FullScoreAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> batting_order;
    private List<JSONObject> player_key;
    int size=0;
    String batting_ord="";
    public static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public FullScoreAdapter(Context context,List<String> batting_order,List<JSONObject> player_key){
        this.context=context;
        this.batting_order=batting_order;

        if (batting_order != null && !batting_order.isEmpty()) {
             size = batting_order.size();
        }
        this.player_key=player_key;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.batting_order.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return batting_order.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public class Holder {
        TextView txtname;
        TextView txtballs;
        TextView txtRuns;
        TextView txtsixs;
        TextView txtfours;
        TextView txtout;
        ImageView strike_ball;
        LinearLayout out_layout_hide;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder= new Holder();
        Typeface tf;
        String fullname="",Balls="",Runs="",sixes="",fours="";


        if(convertView==null) {
            inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);//Here i got an error like java.lang.nullpointerException
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_rows, null);
            tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(convertView.getResources().getAssets(), "Roboto-Regular.ttf");

            holder.txtname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            holder.txtname.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);

            holder.txtballs = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBalls);
            holder.txtballs.setTypeface(tf);

            holder.txtRuns=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtRuns);
            holder.txtRuns.setTypeface(tf);

            holder.txtsixs=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSixs);
            holder.txtsixs.setTypeface(tf);

            holder.txtfours=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFours);
            holder.txtfours.setTypeface(tf);

            holder.txtout=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.out);
            holder.txtout.setTypeface(tf);

            holder.strike_ball=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.strike_ball);

            holder.out_layout_hide=(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.out_layout_color);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            try {
                JSONObject obj = this.player_key.get(position);

                batting_ord=this.batting_order.get(position);

                fullname=obj.getString("fullname");

                JSONObject match=obj.getJSONObject("match");

                JSONObject bats_innings=match.getJSONObject("innings");

                JSONObject first_inning=bats_innings.getJSONObject("1");

                JSONObject first_batting=first_inning.getJSONObject("batting");
                if(first_batting.isNull("balls")) {
                    if(first_batting.isNull("runs")){
                        Runs="0";
                    }
                    else{
                        Runs=first_batting.getString("runs");
                    }
                    Balls="0";
                    sixes="0";
                    fours="0";
                }
                else{

                    Balls=first_batting.getString("balls");
                    Runs=first_batting.getString("runs");
                    sixes=first_batting.getString("sixes");
                    fours=first_batting.getString("fours");
                }

                try{
                    if(first_batting.has("out_str")){
                        String out=first_batting.getString("out_str");
                        holder.txtout.setText(out);
                        holder.strike_ball.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    else{
                        holder.strike_ball.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.txtout.setText("not out");
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                holder.txtname.setText(fullname);
                holder.txtRuns.setText(Runs);
                holder.txtballs.setText(Balls);
                holder.txtfours.setText(fours);
                holder.txtsixs.setText(sixes);

            }
            catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int setcolor=position;

            if(setcolor%2==0){
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                holder.out_layout_hide.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EFF5F5"));
            }
            else{
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                holder.out_layout_hide.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EFF5F5"));
            }
        }
        else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent player_intent=new Intent(context, PlayerIccStats.class);
                player_intent.putExtra("player_key",batting_order.get(position));
                context.startActivity(player_intent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Error i got when my tabs are loaded at the time i pressed a back button.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at adapter.FullScoreAdapter.getView(FullScoreAdapter.java:78)
    at comman.Helper.getListViewSize(Helper.java:20)
    at fragments.OneFragment$JSONLoader.onPostExecute(OneFragment.java:593)
    at fragments.OneFragment$JSONLoader.onPostExecute(OneFragment.java:300) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please Help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: smothly load data?? use recyclerView

Comment: Where i used recyclerView???

Comment: no i am telling you if you want to load data smoothly use RecyclerView

Comment: Using a recycler view instead of a listview with the holder pattern shouldn't bring any noticeable performance improvement

using a recyclerview is more flexible and a good exercice in learning.  there are only a few cases where listview might be preferable to a recyclerview (e.g. you don't need to re-use views)

Comment: are your Fragment like ONE,TWO,THREE etc. fetching any data from server? If yes than can you post the relevant code for that. Or simply post the code for OneFragment.java

Comment: i post the whole code that necessary for my question.

Comment: which line is `FullScoreAdapter.java:78` ? mark it in your code above plz

Comment: inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); this line got an error

Comment: nothing in this line can be null except `context` so make sure you are passing a valid `context` to the adapter constructor. i.e when you instantiate it `FullScoreAdapter adapter = new FullScoreAdapter(...`

Comment: maybe `getContext()` returns `null`, try to use `getActivity()` instead

Comment: Ok i will try to put

Comment: post the asynctask code inside OneFragment.java

Comment: asyncode is already inside the oneFragment

Comment: I know asynctask is inside oneFragment. I am not able to see the code for that asynctask inside oneFragment. Can you post that?

Comment: Inside the asynctask class onpostExecute() call the adapter

Comment: adapter = new FullScoreAdapter(getContext(), p_name, p_key);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
lst.setAdapter(adapter);
Helper.getListViewSize(lst); this is the code